# Нужны ли здесь запятые после слова "несправедливость"?

Tags: пунктуация

Его больше волновала та несправедливость между помещиком и крестьянином.

Answer (score 1):

Никакие запятые здесь не нужны. Это простое предложение, в котором нет причастного и деепричастного оборота или каких-то других нюансов, требующих постановки запятой (запятых). Но вообще предложение корявое, лучше его переделать. Например: Его больше волновала несправедливость, существующая в отношениях между помещиком и крестьянином.

Comment: Большое спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

В этом предложении может возникнуть вопрос по поводу **местоимения "та"**, которое в данном случае имеет дополнительное усилительное значение.

**Сравнить:** Его больше волновала **та** несправедливость, **которая** существует между помещиком и крестьянином. Это уже СПП с придаточным определительным и указательном словом "та".

Answer (score 0):

Его больше волновала та несправедливость между помещиком и крестьянином. 
Да, предложение в таком виде выглядит незаконченным, так как указательное местоимение ТА требует продолжения, чтобы было точно указано, какая именно несправедливость. А в разговорном варианте можно так и оставить, не исправлять и не ставить запятую после ТА.